# Why the bvar command provides this error?

Tags: var, numeric, bayesian, nas, forecast

I run the following bayesain var code but I've got an error

```
x <- bvar(Data, lags = 1, n_draw = 1000L, n_burn = 200L, verbose = FALSE)
Error in bvar(Data, lags = 1, n_draw = 1000L, n_burn = 200L, verbose = FALSE) : 
  Problem with the data. Make sure it is numeric, without any NAs.
```

the data are the following ( year quantity price)

[image]

Comment: Can you include the code you wrote that generated the error? Also I don't think this is tagged correctly, it looks like R language but that has not been included in the list of tags.

Comment: I tried to use the bvar command (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BVAR/BVAR.pdf) but without sucess. the data are price and quantities. 
Thanks